# Соединить две таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table1
----------------
IdFrom | IdTable
----------------
 01    | 1000 
 01    | 2000 
 01    | 3000 
 01    | 4000 
 07    | 2000 
 07    | 2010 
 08    | 1000 
 08    | 1001 

Table2
----------------
IdFrom | IdTable
----------------
 01    | 00000 
 07    | 00000
 08    | 00000
```

Чтобы получилось

```
Table 3
----------------
IdFrom | IdTable
----------------
 01    | 00000
 01    | 1000 
 01    | 2000 
 01    | 3000 
 01    | 4000 
 07    | 00000
 07    | 2000 
 07    | 2010 
 08    | 00000
 08    | 1000 
 08    | 1001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вот так

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 UNION SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Comment: Если не нужно устранять дубликаты, можно юзать `union all`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Table1
union
select * from Table2
order by IdFrom, IdTable
```